# User must implement CanResetPassword interface. Password Reset Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

```
password reset issue

User.php

namespace App;
use Eloquent;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticableTrait;
```

class User extends Eloquent implements Authenticatable
{
    use AuthenticableTrait;

Comment: Seems pretty clear. Have you tried getting your class to implement this trait?

Comment: I get error "User must implement CanResetPassword interface.in PasswordBroker.php line 193" when I click to forgot password. App using Laravel 5.4, login with Auth.

Answer (score 0):

Add the interface CanResetPassword to your User class:

```
// at the top of the file
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;

// at the class declaration
class User extends Eloquent implements Authenticatable, CanResetPassword
{
    // ...
}
```